# How do the LT and GT opcodes differ from SLT and SGT respectively?

Tags: solidity, evm, opcode, yul

When reading the [Opcodes for the EVM](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/evm/opcodes/) article, I saw that the `LT` and `SLT` opcodes are evaluated to the same expression (a < b), as well as the `GT` and `SGT` opcodes (a > b).

How do `LT` and `GT` differ from `SLT` and `SGT` respectively?

Answer (score 1):

The `LT` and `GT` opcodes work with the **unsigned** integers, while `SLT` and `SGT` - with the **signed** ones.

The difference consists in how they interpret the "sign bit":

- in the case of signed integers, it's evaluated to a plus or a minus, while
- in the case of the unsigned integers, it is interpreted as having a numerical value.